# Save model with many to many relationship with Yii

Tags: php, yii, many-to-many, relationship

I have 3 tables like that : User(ID,Name) | Tutorial(ID, Tutcontent) | UserTutorial (ID, IDUser, IDTutorial). I use this code to save model

```
    $user = User::model()->findByPk(1);
    $tutorial = Tutorial::model()->findByPk(1);
    $userTutorial = new UserTutorial;
    $userTutorial->IDUser = $user->ID;
    $userTutorial->IDTutorial = $tutorial->ID;
    $userTutorial->save();
```

It don't save new record in mydatabase

Answer (score 1):

This is a very helpful extension for your task : [CAdvancedArBehavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/cadvancedarbehavior/)
Don't forget to to correctly define the model's relations: [A great tutorial about relations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr)

Comment: Thank so much, but i still get problem.
I copy `CAdvancedArBehavior.php` to extension directory, change in `main.php` 'import' =>array('application.extensions.CAdvancedArBehavior'), in `Post.php` relationship add 'categories'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Category', 'categorypost(postid, categoryid)'), and below it i add  public function behaviors(){return array( 'CAdvancedArBehavior' => array('class' => 'application.extensions.CAdvancedArBehavior'));}
In `PostController.php` add public function actionNewPost() {
$post = new Post();
$post->categories = Category::model()->findAll();
$post->save();}

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
    $user = User::model()->findByPk(1);
    $tutorial = Tutorial::model()->findByPk(1);
    $userTutorial = new UserTutorial;
    $userTutorial->IDUser = $user->ID;
    $userTutorial->IDTutorial = $tutorial->ID;
    $userTutorial->save(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$user = User::model()->findByPk(1);
$tutorial = Tutorial::model()->findAll("id=2");     
$user->**RELATION_ALIAS** = $tutorial;
$user->save();
```